# Getting only "normal" contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

Currently in my application I fetch all the contacts with the followign Cursor query.

```
String[] columnsToReturn = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
};

Cursor contactsCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, columnsToReturn, null, null, null);
```

This returns all contacts, including Skype, WhatsApp etc. I don't want these. I only want the "normal" ones. Those that aren't for any apps, just those stored on your Google accounts. How do I do this?

Also, can I exclude the user's own entries? For example, my name appears multiple times on the list for all of my different email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The `ContactsContract.Contacts` table contains "consolidated" contacts.

> ... a record per aggregate of raw contacts representing the same
>   person.

If you want to query contacts of a particular account or account type, you need to use `RawContacts`. For example, for Google contacts this would be:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
        RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
        RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
        new String[] { "com.google" },
        null);

ArrayList<String> myContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
int contactNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
while (c.moveToNext())
{
    // You can also read RawContacts.CONTACT_ID to read the
    // ContactsContract.Contacts table or any of the other related ones.
    myContacts.add(c.getString(contactNameColumn));
}
```